# How to display JSON data in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xampp

I have a database and a table in it. The table contains the movie names and the images. I am using the XAMP as localhost. I am able to get the data from the table and display it in the table cells in my simulator. But,when I try to launch the app in my device, I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

When I launch the app in simulator, I get a table view with the movie name and images in it,but when i launch the app in device ,it gets crashed.

Could anyone help me out,if I need to change anything regarding the IP addresses or do I need to change the url?

```
#define kGETUrl @"http://localhost/getjson.php"
```

Comment: `localhost` refers to your computer, which works when the simulator is running. `localhost` when running on the device would (presumably) refer to the device itself, which isn't running a web server.

Comment: i can access the localhost from my iphone through safari. Correct me if i am wrong: "  do i need to change the http proxy settings in the wifi section?

Comment: if you type in `http://localhost/getjson.php` on your iPhone, what happens?

Comment: nothing, safari cant connect to the server

Comment: i can only access the local host is i use the wifi IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the url to something that look like this:

```
#define kGETUrl @"http://your-wifi-IP/getjson.php"
```